# Clarity custom validation for specific field

Tags: angular, forms, validation, vmware-clarity

Is there any way to validation partial form based on requirement?

Build with:
Angular 7, [Clarity](https://v1.clarity.design)

Actually, I've one form [clrForm](https://v1.clarity.design/forms) with some fields and two buttons.
Fields are like:

- Field 1: Name
- Field 2: URL
- Field 3: Date

Buttons are like:

- Button 1: Verify
- Button 2: Submit

**Case 1:** When hit on the `Submit` button, validate the complete form. And it's working fine.

**Case 2:** When hit on `Verify`. validate only Field 1 & 2. I don't know how to do it?

Please help on how to do it... The code example is taken from [Clarity form page](https://v1.clarity.design/forms#top).

Thanks

***UPDATE***:

**Form HTML**

```
<form class="clr-form clr-form-compact" clrForm #submitData="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitProfileData(submitData)">
    <clr-input-container >
        <label for="forname" class="clr-control-label required">Name</label>
        <input clrInput type="text" class="clr-input" [(ngModel)]="formData.name" name="lblName" #lblName="ngModel" id="forname" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" required>
        <clr-control-error class="clr-col-12 clr-col-md-8" *clrIfError="'required'">Name is required.</clr-control-error>
    </clr-input-container>

    <clr-input-container >
        <label for="url" class="clr-control-label clr-col-12 clr-col-md-4 required">URL</label>
        <input clrInput type="text" class="clr-input" [(ngModel)]="formData.url" name="lblUrl" #lblUrl="ngModel" id="url" placeholder="URL" [pattern]="SOME_URL_PATTERN" required>
        <clr-control-error class="clr-col-12 clr-col-md-8" *clrIfError="'required'">URL is reqyured.</clr-control-error>
        <clr-control-error class="clr-col-12 clr-col-md-8" *clrIfError="'pattern'" >Invalid URL given.</clr-control-error>
    </clr-input-container>

    <div class="clr-col-lg-12 clr-col-md-12 clr-col-12 text-right py-1 pr-0">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" (click)="verifyTenantData()">Verify</div><!-- HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO VALIDATE PARTIAL FORM-->
    </div>

    <clr-date-container>
        <label for="startdate" class="clr-control-label clr-col-12 required">Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="startdate" [(ngModel)]="formData.startDate" name="lblStartDt" #lblStartDt="ngModel" placeholder="Date" [(clrDate)]="formData.isoStartDate" required>
        <clr-control-error class="clr-col-12 clr-col-md-8" *clrIfError="'required'">Date is require</clr-control-error>
    </clr-date-container>
<form>
<div class="clr-row ">
    <div class="clr-col-lg-12 text-center my-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitData.ngSubmit.emit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
submitData(submitData) {
    if (submitData.valid) {
       //SUBMIT DATA CODE
    } else {
        this.clrForm.markAsDirty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how Angular's reactive forms work?

Comment: @wentjun Yes, I'm. But this is related to clarity form validation. which have own tags to show up validations. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: I see.. But are you referring to the 'Verify' button? Or 'Submit' button? So you want the validation text from `<clr-control-error>` to appear when you click the button?

Comment: Submit button will validate complete form but verify button will only go for Field 1 and & 2. Let me correct my question.

Comment: Can you include your code too? I need to see what you have written so far, and your formgroup/formcontrol names

Comment: @wentjun Added example code. Not using form groups. I checked this example(https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-password-confirm-validator?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) before post.

Answer (score 1):

Clarity depends upon Angular's form validation (works with reactive and template-driven) to determine when a control is invalid. It does this by inspecting the NgControl and seeing if there is an error. It sounds like you have two questions.

1. How do I force validation errors on submit/verify?
2. How do I make a custom validator rule?

For the first question, controls are only validated by Clarity after they are touched, to avoid showing errors prematurely. If you want to force validation then you would use the `ClrForm.markAsDirty()` (pre 2.0) or `ClrForm.markAsTouched()` (2.0+) API. This will essentially trigger all form controls to validate immediately and display any errors.

In template driven forms, you need to get a reference to the form in your controller.

```
@ViewChild(ClrForm) form: ClrForm;
```

Then you can call the method in your validate button handler. Do not submit the form.

```
validate() {
  this.form.markAsDirty(); // 1.0
  //this.form.markAsTouched(); // 2.0+
}
```

For the second question, the [Angular forms validation documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) covers it well and I also suggest looking at this example from my book of a [phone number validator](https://github.com/angular-in-action/invoice/blob/master/src/app/validators/phone.directive.ts) directive for NgModel, which depends upon a [validator function](https://github.com/angular-in-action/invoice/blob/master/src/app/validators/phone.validator.ts).

If you had this in your project, you'd simply add the `phone` attribute to your input to add the validator, and Angular (and Clarity) would be aware of it. Then you could write a custom error message like so:

```
<clr-control-error *clrIfError="'phone'">Not a valid phone number</clr-control-error>
```

If you want a generic error message, leave off the `clrIfError` directive and it will show for *any* error.

Lastly, your submit button can just be `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>` instead of grabbing a reference to the form and manually calling the submit event.

Comment: The rules still apply for a partial form, you will just have to manually call the form control `markAsDirty()` API instead of the whole form.